# replacing HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse with spring annotations

Tags: spring, annotations

So, I am currently trying to replace the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` variables in my Spring 3.0 controller methods. I recently I know that I can replace the following old methods with:

```
 HttpServletRequest.getParameter       -> @RequestParameter
 HttpServletRequest.getCookies         -> @CookieValue //with actual name no array indexing!
 HttpServletRequest.getPathInfo        -> @PathValue   //with actual name no array indexing!
 HttpServletRequest.getHeader          -> @RequestHeader
 HttpServletResponse.getWriter().write -> <just return a String>
```

I am sure there are more and I would really like to implement as many of these shortcuts as possible. can anyone point me a resource with a complete list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Reference is your friend! Just scroll over the [table of content](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/) for section "22.3.3. Defining @RequestMapping handler methods"

So some annotation you missed:

- `@RequestBody`
- `@SessionAttribute`
- `@MatrixVariable`

But there are also some shortcuts that do not require an annotation, instead they are just mapped by there type (have a look at [Supported method argument types](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-arguments)):

- `Locale`
- `HttpSession`
- `HttpEntity`
- ...

Comment: Ahh, I forgot to mention RequestBody I have used it, that one's great! . SessionAttribute looks promising, but MatrixVariable just gives a map of names to values right? that's the sort of thing I'm trying to avoid